# Microsoft cognitive service for detection of animal in images

Tags: vb.net, azure-cognitive-services

please  can any one guide me ,I have learnt that cognitive service of Microsoft can help us to detect contents in images using different api,is there any cognitive service that helps to detect details about any animal that is in images?

like

[image]

description like, outdoor, grass,calf,fearing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same question as [Discussion: How to use visual recognition to locate a dandelion weed or flower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530182/discussion-how-to-use-visual-recognition-to-locate-a-dandelion-weed-or-flower/44530560#44530560).

> You can use Computer Vision (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) to start with, but you may find that it detects "flower" but not necessarily "dandelion". If the recognition is not as accurate as you need it to be then you can use Custom Vision (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/) where you can train the API to recognize the specific objects that you are interested in.